Made My Android Samsung Phone Screen Strectched
I previously did this on Windows Laptop and I didn't know how to do it in Android Phone.
On Windows Laptop (using AMD GPU):

I downloaded CRU (Custom Resolution Utility) and extracted the zip folder.
I opened CRU folder and launched CRU.exe.
I added a new resolution for 920x1080 (portrait mode) with a refresh rate of 100 Hz.
I went to Settings > System > Display and changed the resolution from 1920x1080 to 920x1080.
I noticed two black bars on the left and right sides of the display.
To achieve a stretched screen, I opened "AMD Radeon Software" application.
In the display section, I changed "Scaling Mode" from "Center" to "Full Panel".
The display screen stretched to remove all black bars.
Stretched display means all content (items, fonts, icons, etc.) expands without changing position, it also will not reduce the number of items inside it (like text wrapping)

For Android Device (Samsung Galaxy S23):

I connected Samsung Galaxy S23 (base model, neither "Plus" nor "Ultra") via USB Cable.
I enabled "USB Debugging" and "Wireless Debugging".
I verified connection with adb devices.
I set screen size to 1080x2600 with adb shell wm size 1080x2600 to create black bars on the left and right.
I attempted to adjust density to 200 with adb shell wm density 200, but only font size reduced (not stretch my screen).
I reset density with adb shell wm density reset.
I tried to remove black bars with adb shell wm overscan 0,0,0,0, but it has already deprecated.

Question: Is there any way to achieve the same stretched screen behavior I experienced on my AMD laptop on my Samsung Galaxy S23 device?
I wanted from this:

to this:

